# Little $o$ and Big $O$ notations

Tags: calculus, notation

I see frequently the notations $f=o(g)$ and $f=O(g)$ (also in the wikipedia) and I can understand their meaning. The thing I somehow do not understand is why the equality $=$ is used and not the symbol "belongs to", $f\in o(g)$ or $f\in O(g)$ ?The notations $o(g)$ , $O(g)$ are sets of functions, are not they?... Thanks.

Comment: The definitions (and related conventions) for $o(g)$ and $O(g)$ differ from field to field. In my field, for example, such an expression stands for an unspecified function—for example, we might write $(x+1)^{3/2} = x^{3/2} + O(\sqrt x)$ (as $x\to\infty$), or $(x+1)^{3/2} - x^{3/2} = O(\sqrt x)$. In other fields, these expressions stand for sets of functions.

Comment: It is a simple abuse of notation that makes some formulæ easier to read.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We can read in the classic *[Asymptotic Methods  in Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486642216)* by N.G. De  Bruijn:
>
> - The common interpretation of all these formulas can be expressed as  follows. Any expression involving the $O$-symbol is  to be considered as a class of functions. ... Sometimes the left-hand-side of a relation is not a class, but a single function, ... Then the relation means that the function on the left is a member of the class on the right.
> - It is obvious that the sign $=$ is really the wrong sign for such relations, because  it  suggests symmetry, and  there is no such symmetry. For example  $O(x)=(x^2)\   (x\to\infty)$  is correct,  but $O(x^2)=O(x) \ (x\to\infty)$ is false.  Once this warning has  been given,  there is,  however, not  much harm in using the sign $=$, and  we shall maintain it, for no other reason than that it is customary.

The phrase ... than that it is customary ... indicates *tradition* as reason for this somewhat peculiar misuse of notation. This is nicely explained in section 9.2, p. 446 of *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.